# bash execute code stopped after execute ' sudo -i'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
# !/bin/bash
sudo  -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted  universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-precise.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
sudo  apt-get update
```

when I   execute this script ,it just  do 'sudo -i ' then  stop, who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` manpage says :

> -i,--login
>        Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐base entry as a login shell.
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

No wonder the execution of your script stops.

The commands

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
.
.
sudo  apt-get update
```

are never reached  because you have just spawned a new shell with `sudo -i`.

As [[ @mona_sax ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6379160/mona-sax) suggested in comment,running a script as sudo may not be a good idea in the security context. It's not clear what your actual intention is, but if the intention is to run the script in background then remove `sudo  -i` line and do :

```
./script 2>&1 1>/dev/null &
```

Comment: `sudo ./script` is a bad idea.

Comment: @mona_sax : Updated :)

Comment: I means  when  script execute  ‘sudo -i', then  terminal ask me input password,  after I input password why   bash don't execute the nex code?

Comment: @YongDeng `If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.` is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify a command to run as root, `sudo` invokes an interactive shell.  It won't terminate until you `exit` from it (or it is killed by a signal, etc).

If you need it to return immediately, you could pass `true` as the command:

```
sudo true
```

However, in your case, it's probably better, given what you're doing, to just limit the script to only superusers:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# check we are running as root
if [ $(id -u) != "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: this script must be run as a superuser" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Then it is up to the user to gain appropriate privileges, rather than encoding that into the script.